# Adding a daemon process in Android and SELinux

Tags: android, android-source, selinux

I am struggling to add a daemon process for system (not vendor). I added this process to init.rc:

```
service start_md /system/bin/start_md
   class core
   user root
   seclabel u:r:start_md:s0
```

in start_md.te:

```
  type start_md, domain;
  type start_md_exec, exec_type, file_type, system_file_type;
  typeattribute start_md coredomain;
  init_daemon_domain(start_md)
```

in file_contexts:

```
  /system/bin/start_md           u:object_r:start_md_exec:s0
```

Also added attributes in compat 33.0.cli

I keep getting an avc denial {entry_point} for start_md system_file no matter what I do. When I add (I got this line from audit tool):

```
allow start_md system_file:file entry_point;
```

it does not compile saying it fails due to this line in public/domain.te (line 415):

```
neverallow * { file_type -exec_type -postinstall_file }:file entrypoint;
```

This line specifies entrypoint being allowed for only exec type or postinstall file. start_md_exec is already of exec_type! I am clueless and documentation is lacking

Comment: Remove "seclabel u:r:start_md:s0"